# Float property non-zero default, is it possible?

Tags: delphi, properties, floating-point, components

I would like to use a float property in my component, but set it to some non-zero default value (let's say it is 1000.0). If I try to do this in the Create, the property start to behave wildly since the default value for floats it 0 (see *classes.TWriter.WriteProperty.WriteFloatProp.IsDefaultValue*) so when I override some value with 0 in the form designer, delphi doesn't save this value (it's default in this case), but my Create will set it to 1000.0 when the compoent will be loaded the next time, so the actually I have the value I didn't set.

The problem is that there is no way to set default with 'default' directive (the compiler says '*Default values must be of ordinal, pointer or small set type*') and it's also not possible to force storing with stored directive, it doesn't work (Delphi 5)

So is there a chance to find a workaround?

Thanks,

Max

Comment: I am very interested in a solution to this problem as well. Did you ever figure out a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can used the `stored` directive:

```
property MyFloat: Float read GetValue write SetValue stored IsMyFloatStored;
```

with a Boolean function `IsMyFloatStored` that returns True iff MyFloat doesn't have its default value.

Comment: Ulrich, I hoped that it would help, but it looks like stored filter works before the default value processing so it can't be used to overwrite default comparison processing

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by implementing the DefineProperties method in my descendant of TPersistent. I       wanted to make a general solution to this problem that I could easily implement in all of       my objects for all the relevant properties. Here's how it looks:

```
  TOverridePropFiler = class
    private
      FReadWritePropName: string;
      FObject: TObject;
      procedure ReadOverrideProp(Reader: TReader);
            procedure WriteOverrideProp(Writer: TWriter);
    public
      constructor Create(Filer:TFiler; Obj:TObject; Name:string);
    end;

  { TOverridePropFiler }

  constructor TOverridePropFiler.Create(Filer:TFiler; Obj:TObject; Name:string);
  begin
    FReadWritePropName:=Name;
    FObject:=obj;
    if (Name='') or not Assigned(GetPropInfo(Obj,Name)) then
      Raise Exception.CreateFmt('Property %s not found in object %s',[Name,Obj.ClassName]);
    Filer.DefineProperty(Name, ReadOverrideProp, WriteOverrideProp,
      GetPropValue(FObject,FReadWritePropName,False)<>uiFloat);
  end;

  procedure TOverridePropFiler.ReadOverrideProp(Reader: TReader);
  begin
    SetPropValue(FObject,FReadWritePropName,Reader.ReadFloat);
  end;

  procedure TOverridePropFiler.WriteOverrideProp(Writer: TWriter);
  begin
    Writer.WriteDouble(GetPropValue(FObject,FReadWritePropName,False));
  end;
```

I call it in my DefineProperties method as follows:

```
  procedure TMyObj.DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler);
  begin
    inherited;
    TOverridePropFiler.Create(Filer,Self,'dTOverride').Free;
  end;
```

To make this generalized, I had to use RTTI and save the property name locally (It's not possible to get this out of TWriter, and requires a hack for TReader). To make it thread safe (and because TFiler.DefineProperty wants "of object" functions) I encapsulated the whole thing in an object.

In my case I want the default value to be uiFloat. This constant can be set to whatever you want. If you want different defaults for different properties, you could easily add the default as a parameter to the Create function.

Note that you still have to set the property to the default in TMyObj's constructor.

This seems to me to be a fairly efficient way to work around a pretty serious limitation in Delphi.

Edit: You need to remember to add "stored false" to all of the properties that use this.

Answer (score 1):

Just came across this problem and solved it by setting the value I want as default in the constructor and using the **nodefault** directive for that property.

Answer (score 0):

As the compiler says, floating-point values cannot have a default value. The only thing I can think of is to store the floating-point value in a scaled integer. For instance, if you only need three decimals of `yourFloat`, you can store `yourInt = 1000 * yourFloat` instead. The default value would then be `yourInt := 1000000`, corresponding to `yourFloat := 1000.000`.

Of course, you can do this a bit more elegantly, like

```
  private
    FMyFloat: real;
    function GetValue: integer;
    procedure SetValue(Value: integer);

  published
    property MyInteger: integer read GetValue write SetValue default 1000000;

implementation

function TMyClass.GetValue: integer;
begin
  result := round(1000 * FMyFloat);
end;

procedure TMyClass.SetValue(Value: integer);
begin
  FMyFloat := Value / 1000;
end;
```

This way you will still only see the floating-point field `FMyFloat` from inside the class itself. But the property will be a scaled integer, and thus perfectly storable.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it should behave like float in the designer. Just thought that a string property (that accepts only correctly formatted floats) could be another alternative

Answer (score 0):

The Default value actually only tells the stream code what the default value is, and if it is that value, then it is not streamed. This saves having to stream all the default values. The component must actually set the default in the .Create anyway. The compiler does not do any magic to set the default for you.

In this case, it will not matter, as you can set the default value in your .Create constructor, and then just leave out the default in the definition. The value will always be stored, but it will work as you want.

Comment: No, the actual code from VCL breaks my intentions. Look, if you change the value to 0 for float, the value won't be streamed. in this case there's no overriding of the property I set in Create. in other words my hand (when I pressed Enter) wanted to change some value to zero, but when the form is loaded it will return to my non-zero default (since there was no streaming).